# Replacing empty or missing values with zeros in a large array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace, int

I have an large array of more than 40000 elements

```
a = ['15', '12', '', 18909, ...., '8989', '', '90789', '8']
```

I'm looking for a simply way to replace the empty '' values to '0' so that I can manipulate the data in the array using Numpy.

I would then convert the elements in my array into integers using

```
a = map(int, a)
```

so that I could find the mean of the array in numpy

```
a_mean = np.mean(a)
```

My issue is that I cannot convert to integers in an array with missing numbers to get a mean.

Comment: Can you do: `new_a = [int(v or 0) for v in a]` and then use `new_a`?

Comment: I believe you can use `numpy.nan_to_num` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a small function that converts a single value exactly how you want it, e.g.:

```
def to_int(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return 0
```

which can be used with `map`:

```
In [22]: a = ['15', '12', '', 18909, '8989', '90789', '8']

map(to_int, a)
Out[23]: [15, 12, 0, 18909, 8989, 90789, 8]
```

in a list comprehension:

```
In [25]: np.array([to_int(x) for x in a])
Out[25]: array([   15,    12,     0, 18909,  8989, 90789,     8])
```

or in a generator expression to directly create a numpy array:

```
In [27]: np.fromiter((to_int(x) for x in a), dtype=int)
Out[27]: array([   15,    12,     0, 18909,  8989, 90789,     8])
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the simple and clean solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you right so it should look like that:

```
for index in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] is '':
       a[i] = '0'
```

You can also use:

```
a = list(map(lambda x: '0' if x == '' else x, a))
```

Answer (score 1):

From the previous learning with SO, i see you can impy the below solution to convert the NaN to zeros..

```
from numpy import *

a = array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, NaN]])
where_are_NaNs = isnan(a)
a[where_are_NaNs] = 0
```

secondly, `nan_to_num()`  as i said earlier in my comment.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, np.NaN]])
>>> a
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.],
       [  3.,   4.,  nan]])
>>> a = np.nan_to_num(a)
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

A more verbose answer is:

```
acc = 0
for v in a:
    acc+=int(v or 0)
a_mean = acc/len(a)
```